# Converting a decimal to int?

Tags: c

How can I make a decimal number to an int. For example, how can I make 0.565 to 565 (Without multiplying by the power of 10) because I wouldn't know how many numbers after decimal point will be there. Because these are user inputs.

Comment: Could you detail a little bit what the user is allowed to type in? If the number of number after the decimal point is unlimited, you should take it as a string and count how many numbers there are after the decimal point and use this count as the power of 10.

Answer (score 3):

> How can I make a decimal number to an int. For example, how can I make 0.565 to 565 (Without multiplying by the power of 10) because I wouldn't know how many numbers after decimal point will be there. Because these are user inputs.

Accept the inputs as *strings*.  Parse the strings to identify the fractional part of each, and go from there.  That's much easier than starting from a `float` or `double` value, because details of floating-point representation get in the way, such as 0.565 not being exactly representable in binary floating-point.

Answer (score -1):

This should do:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>


int main(void)
{
  long double ld, ldi;
  long long int lli;

  {
    int n;

    do
    {
      n = scanf("%Lf", &ld);
    } while (1 != n);
  }

  while (LDBL_EPSILON < fabsl(modfl(ld, &ldi))) {
    ld *= 10.;
    fprintf(stderr, "%.30Lf\n", ld);
  }

  lli = (long long int) ldi;
  printf("%lld\n", lli);
}
```

<sup>*if `LDBL_EPSILON` is missing try `__LDBL_EPSILON __` or alike ...*</sup>

Comment: This sort of thing is almost always a bad idea.  This is probably the most carefully-written implementation of this bad idea I've ever seen -- kudos for that -- but it's still a bad idea.

Comment: @SteveSummit: I claim it's carefull enough to show how to do math under the assumption the math lib isnt't broken.